# Java Import from another package of the same Project is Not Working in my ECLIPSE

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, import

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uopho.png)I have a java project titled "ProjectWithMaven". In there src/main/java , I have created different packages com.states , com.tutorial , com.map etc.
Now I want a java entity class StudentTable from com.tutorial into my com.states java main class "StateDemo.java"  like this below.
//Main Pgm

```
    package com.states;

    import org.hibernate.Session;
       import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
       import org.hibernate.Transaction;
       import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
    import com.tutorial.StudentTable;
    
    public class StateDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    System.out.println("Eg:- ");
    SessionFactory f= new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

    //Create Student OBJECT:
    StudentTable std = new StudentTable;
    //properties SET: Get

    std.setStudName("Samudra Dutta Gupta");
    std.setStudRno(54);
    Session s = f.openSession();
    Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
    s.save(std);
    tx.commit();
    
    s.close();
    f.close();
}
```

}//main class

StudentTable std = new StudentTable()
keep showing ERROR to imprt the StudentTable class even after importing it.

But I cant import StudentTable from com.tutorial.StudentTable.
It s keep showing options to import / project fix etc... and Other Options

(Note: StudentTable is a java Entity class. I m also using Java Hibernate ).
I am unable To understand What mistake I have made.
I am unable to remove the error that is stopping from Running my main class.

I m using Eclipse IDE. Does it have something to do with Eclipse Configurations?

Comment: Is it in the same project?

Comment: yes same project.

Comment: This code is not correct `StudentTable std = new StudentTable;`  Are you sure that all of your code compiles?

Comment: StudentTable std = new StudentTable() ; also NOT working.

Comment: all other classes compiled and Runs.

Comment: *and Runs.* - what do you mean?  You could try to clean your project, if that does not work and everything compiles as you say, then show your directory structure.  And post the actual error message.

Comment: I think it is something to do with my eclipse. Now it s not running any class. Showing this Error msg FOR all, when I try to run my previous pgms .:Error: Could not find or load main class com.tutorial.FetchData
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tutorial.FetchData

Comment: Your screenshot shows that `hibernate.cfg.xml` is in `src/main/java` instead of in `src/main/resources`, so it won't be copied to the output folder and missing when you run your application. There seems to be more errors in `StateDemo.java`, e.g. missing exception handling. All errors and warnings are shown in the _Problems_ view from which you can copy the error messages to your question.

Comment: The red cross next to your StateDemo class means that is has an error.

Comment: thnk u all for ur advices...  :)  I was not able to rectify it... I deleted the entire package.